# For loop in matlab error "Attempted to access index out of bounds because..."

Tags: matlab

I'm new to matlab.
I wrote a function.
when i run my function in workspace at the first FOR i get this error :

```
??? Attempted to access XX(461,:); index out of bounds because
size(XX)=[460,440,3].

Error in ==> FOH_Zoom at 10
XX(j,:)=(XX(2*j-1,:)+XX(2*j+1,:))/2;
```

and this is my function :

```
function XX = FOH_Zoom(img)

X = ones(size(img)); %make a matrix of ones as size as image
XX=imresize(X,2); %make size of matrx double
[a,b]=size(X); %get the size of matrix
XX(1:2:end,1:2:end)=img(:,:); % fill odd rows and columns with original image data
[m,n]=size(XX);

for j=1:m-1
 XX(j,:)=(XX(2*j-1,:)+XX(2*j+1,:))/2;
 end

for i=1:n
 XX(:,i)=(XX(:,2*i-1)+XX(:,2*i+1))/2;
  end

 imshow(XX); % show image
  title([num2str(m),' *** ',num2str(n)]);
  end
```

what is the problem ,do you think?
any help really appriciate
regards.

Comment: your code breaks if the matrix `img` is 3D (i.e an RGB image).

Comment: thanks for your reply .But my image isn't RGB it's a grayscale one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `XX` is 3D, so you have to use `size` like this,

```
[m,n,~]=size(XX);
```

Because:

```
 XX=zeros(460,440,3);
 [m,n]=size(XX)

 m = 460
 n = 1320
```

While,

```
 [m,n,~]=size(XX)

 m = 460
 n = 440
```

**Second Problem**

in Line 10 you have,

```
XX(j,:)=(XX(2*j-1,:)+XX(2*j+1,:))/2;
```

When `m = 231` then `2xm-1 = 461`, and you will get the error out of bound,

I don't know what you want to do, but changing `for j = 1 : m/2` and `for i = 1 : n/2` would help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.i change this[m,n]=size(XX) to  [m,n,~]=size(XX);but i recieve this error "??? Error: File: FOH_Zoom.m Line: 7 Column: 7
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket."

Comment: @delkook, which one is column7 line7? the same line of `[m,n,~]=size(XX);`?? are you sure?

Comment: this line  [m,n,~]=size(XX);

Comment: @delkook, first check line6, see if it's okey. If so, then maybe try, `m = size(XX,1); n = size(XX,2);` see if that works.

Comment: I tried this m = size(XX,1); n = size(XX,2); but again the same error occured."??? Attempted to access XX(461,:); index out of bounds because
size(XX)=[460,440,3]."

Comment: @delkook okey there is another problem let me edit the answer.